# How do I bind to bootstrap's modal events in my ember view?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using an ember view to render a modal intro my app, currently it looks like this:

**views/modal.js**

```
App.ModalView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    classNames: ['modal', 'fade'],
    templateName: 'modal',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().modal('show');
    }
});
```

**controller/application.js**

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    showModal: function() {
        var modal = App.ModalView.create();
        modal.append();
    }
});
```

The `modal.hbs` template is just some boilerplate html.

I can show the modal just fine when I trigger my `showModal` function but I haven't been able to remove the view from the DOM after the modal closes, I'm trying to bind to the `hidden` event but I can't figure out how, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you had a look at this ember-addon: https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap it includes also the modal pane well integrated into ember.

Comment: That's a nice option, however I'm trying to learn Ember so it'd be nice to know what I'm doing wrong for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this approach in an existing app, and works well

```
App.ModalView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "modal",
    title: "",
    content: "",
    classNames: ["modal", "fade", "hide"],
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().modal("show");
        this.$().one("hidden", this._viewDidHide);
    },
    // modal dismissed by example clicked in X, make sure the modal view is destroyed
    _viewDidHide: function() {
        if (!this.isDestroyed) {
            this.destroy();
        }
    },
    // here we click in close button so _viewDidHide is called
    close: function() {        
        this.$(".close").click();
    }
});
```

Here we listen the `hidden` event, that is triggered when the modal is completely hidden, to destroy the object. This is important because views created programmatically, calling `view.append()`, isn't destroyed. That approach ensure it.

And this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/tK3rX/) with the example.

Comment: My bad I was using the new bootstrap 3.0 and they changed the event to `hidden.bs.modal`. By the way In your example it should be `this.remove()` not `this.destroy()` thanks anyways!

Comment: The destroy method belongs to ember, its used to remove the view from the dom, remove observers etc. You're welcome @javiervd

Comment: I see, I got a `Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'destroy'` error when I tried to implement it, switching to `remove` worked fine though

Comment: For the sake of learning ember, can you explain the difference between using ```$('.myModal')``` and ```this.$()``` as your selector to attach the ```_viewDidHide``` method?

Comment: For sure. `$('.myModal')` is the jquery selector which is bound to the whole document. The `view.$('.myModal')`, is a kind of alias to $('.myModal', viewContext), where viewContext is the generated dom of the view. So using `this.$()` will always search in the view child nodes, see the [doc](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#method__) for more details.